# FontImage gives NullPointerException

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to instantiate an Image as follow but while on simulator everything seems ok, on Android 4.4 I get a dialog warning about a NullPointerException...

```
Image img = FontImage.createFixed("B", Font.create("native:MainRegular"), 0, 20, 20);
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: on Android 5 it says: "Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.Object com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation$NativeFont.font' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the right API to load the native font so it would return null hence failing the image creation later. Try this:

```
Font fnt = Font.createTrueTypeFont("native:MainRegular", "native:MainRegular");
Image img = FontImage.createFixed("B", fnt, 0, 20, 20);
```